# Seeking Marine Traffic Routes Data?

Tags: routing, marine, data

We are planning to implement a routing application to monitor marine traffic.

The issue is that we either need a data set that has international sea traffic routes data or a clear definition of it.

In both cases, we couldn't find a good resource. We found few resources such as [geoweb.dnv.org/data](http://geoweb.dnv.org/data) and http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3d82f13e484c4d3ca24345b796b76400 but it's limited for few areas, while we need to cover the whole globe.

Any idea?

---

to explain what I'm looking for, please take a look here:
http://www.imo.org/OurWork/Safety/Navigation/Pages/ShipsRouteing.aspx

I found this dataset http://geocommons.com/overlays/25 but it's not quite accurate. I don't think it's based on the standard traffic routing system.

Comment: Email the admin of this site, https://www.marinetraffic.com/? I worked on an offshore windfarm project in the UK a few years back, and marine data was a bit on the scarce side, and not very standardized.

Comment: Good luck. I really enjoyed working on AIS, seeing boats moving around in real time. The most fun I ever had doing Java, though I would certainly use Javascript and something like OpenLayers, if I were to do it again.

Comment: Thanks! that's actually how we're doing it! Javascript, Openlayers with GeoServer and PostGIS. Pretty powerful -open source- collection!

Comment: The best combo. OL didn't exist when I did mine, we used Java and MySQL. I even wrote my own WMS server and the mapping was a giant Swing application. Oh the pain. Enjoy  the lovely new tools we have at our disposal these days :D

Comment: Painful experience indeed! LOL thanks for sharing your expertise!

Comment: I have a colleague who deals with a marine data supplier (and they do some global datasets). She isn't in today, but I will ask her tomorrow for their details. If I don't respond tomorrow, or you don't already have an answer, feel free to message me again for a reminder.

Comment: Many thanks! that would be very much appreciated! Here is my email just in case: shadin.kh@gmail.com

Comment: Have you seen this [website](http://marinecadastre.gov/ais/)?

Comment: A couple of related questions here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22073/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104450/

Comment: @ChrisW Thanks a lot! I've found a data set that gives me a general idea, but it still lacks of many elements such as direction, line width.. etc

Comment: @JohnBarça Hey, Any update from your colleague?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for in terms of direction or 'line width'. I would expect any route to be bi-directional, and ocean-going routes aren't really going to have a 'width' per se. You may want to edit your question to provide additional details about format/attributes you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Shadin did you find the solution you were looking for? I am looking for the same thing so if you can i would really appreciate it if you could let me know where to find it too. I am primarily interested in distance in NM between ports for the different shipping routes of the commercial industry

Comment: We will be happy to help you! Feel free to contact us through the API form here: http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais-api-services/index/ Cheers, Mazin/ MarineTraffic

Comment: If you seek open data (often just any data) the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is usually the best place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Check this one. Please give due credits to authors

https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/globalmarine/data